# Recover a deleted partition by mistake (FAT32)

Tags: hard-drive, partition, data-recovery

I deleted by mistake a FAT32 (I think it was fat32) partition in a external drive, searching I got through this post: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/229699-14-erased-partition-external-hard-drive-mistake-help but trying all the nice tools they talk there the problem is, as the drive is external, it's not even listed among the recoverable drives. It's a 2.5'' portable hard drive, so I don't have a free slot where to insert it as an internal drive.

What can I do to recover the partition? I'm using Windows

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try TestDisk, it's one of the best recovery tool, and it's opensource. (never tried on Windows, but on Linux works great!)

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download

Comment: I tried but it doesn't list the external one, I'll try to put in slot later, as Oldskool sayed

Comment: or you could use a Linux Live distribution that doesn't have limitations of crappy OSes. (http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage)

Answer (score 1):

Portable drives are always a bit tricky here. If possible, I would try to attach the drive to you motherboard directly, even if you don't have a 2,5" to 3,5" bracket converter, you can just put the drive on top of your machine, as long as the SATA/IDE and power cables are long enough to reach the drive, it should work fine.